# Can't pull some docker images: Status 410

Tags: docker

I have a server that started showing this strange behavior. When I try to pull some very common docker images like `docker pull ubuntu:latest` I get the following message as a response:

```
Error: Status 410 trying to pull repository library/ubuntu: "<html>\r\n<head><title>410 Gone</title></head>\r\n<body>\r\n<center><h1>410 Gone</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>openresty</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
```

But if I try for example `docker pull centos:latest`, the image is pulled just fine.

Does anyone have a clue of what the issue might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was due to an ancient version of Docker client. After I was able to update it, I can pull any image just fine.

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2):

> `<body>\r\n<center><h1>410 Gone</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>openresty</center>\r\n</body>`

openresty is a proxy that's installed on your network and is throwing those errors. You'll need to either bypass your proxy or fix it. These are not errors with the docker engine or Docker Hub.

Comment: Strange. I'm pretty sure we did not install anything like this. Could this be an issue within Digital Ocean's network then?